# Breadcrumb Chevrons CSS

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to replicate the chevron breadcrumb code located at: http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/breadcrumbs/demo/demo.html

But can't seem to get it to work.

My HTML & CSS can be found at the CodePen here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNWrLj

Basically, what's going on, is that I'm trying to add the left-side triangular cutout to the breadcrumbs, but it just isn't working.

The cutout is thrown waaaaay to the left-hand side of the screen for some reason, instead of being where it should be.

I also can't use left, right, top, any of that to position the left-side triangular cutout because the content of the breadcrumbs is randomly generated. Could be 1 word, could be 3+ words. Never know. Positioning it statically would just be silly and messy.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="breadcrumbDiv col-lg-12" id="category_bread_crumb">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="categories?catid=">Home</a> </li>
            <li><a href="/Fashion-and-Apparel">Fashion and Apparel</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">Shirts</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you use `:before` and `:after` shown in the demo you're trying to replicate. You could put whatever content you like into the middle section and the `:before` and `:after` will stay `absolute` to that content area as long as it's `position: relative`.

Comment: Hi @ui-matt I am using the :before and :after pseudo selectors. That's the problem. I'm using all of the same code that the example is using.

Comment: I get what you're saying now, will take a look.

Comment: Trim the CSS to the _relevant_ parts only and post in your question. There are literally thousands of lines of CSS in your codepen

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn Roger that. I apologize. It is now trimmed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of pseudo-elements works just fine.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#stages {
  margin:50px;
}

ul, li {
  padding: 0;
  list-style:none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin:0 .5em ;
}

a {
  display: block;
  height:2em;
  line-height:2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding:0 1em;
}

li:before,
li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  width:0;
  height:0;
}

li:after {
  left:100%;
  border: 1em solid transparent;
  border-left-color:lightblue;
}

li:before {
  right:calc(100% - 1em);
  border: 1em solid lightblue;
  border-left-color:transparent;
}

li.current:after {
  border-left-color:#00f;
}

li.current:before {
  border: 1em solid blue;
  border-left-color:transparent;
}

li:first-of-type:before {
    border-left-color:lightblue;
}

li.current:first-of-type:before {
    border-left-color:blue;
}

li.current a {
  background-color: #00f;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id='stages'>
<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Some Very Very Long List Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>  
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo 1**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yNbELx)

[**Codepen Demo 2 now with added icons**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WvjyNM)